# How to set PYTHONPATH in OS X?

Tags: python, macos, bash, pythonpath

Problem: Running Python 2.7.3 with IDLE.  Want to add packages like numpy.  Cannot control where they are installed.  While installing packages using the terminal, I do not seem to be able to direct them to, say,

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

At the same time, cannot tell 2.7.3 to look at where they are no matter what I include in the bash-profile, profile or profile_pysave.  I've read more than 50 suggestions all over the web (including Stackoverflow), but none of them seem to work.

One constraint on the solution is that I do not wish to create an isolated environment as suggested by [PATH issues with homebrew-installed Python 2 and Python 3 on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454187/path-issues-with-homebrew-installed-python-2-and-python-3-on-osx).

This is how my bash-profile looks (yes, I tried using Anaconda, and gave up):

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/python:$PATH"

PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/"
export PYTHONPATH

# added by Anaconda 1.5.1 installer
export PATH="/Users/YalcinU/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

# added by Anaconda 1.5.1 installer
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages   
/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

How can you setup PYTHONPATH in OSX?

Comment: Why do you think you need to control where the packages go? Usually they will go into site-packages by default. And you certainly shouldn't need to add that to PYTHONPATH manually.

Comment: So the numpy is not being recognized from your python scripts? Could you post where the numpy is installed (the full path) and also what the final PYTHONPATH is? (Just run 'echo $PYTHONPATH' )

Comment: Mr. Roseman, I want to control where the packages go so that when I run 2.7.3, it recognizes the packages and allows me to import (it doesn't)--Regards

Comment: Mr. Sangala, here is what the command you suggest generates:   `code`YalcinUmit:~ YalcinU$ echo $PYTHONPATH
:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`code`   Actually, numpy is somehow installed there, but to give you a specific example, when I try to install matplotlib, the installation is aborted because numpy is a dependancy, and cannot be found (I assume it does not look at the site-package location echoed above)--Thanks for your help

Comment: @user2738815 Have you found an answer to your question? I may have a similar problem as you here http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/239910/15504 Which OS X are you running? I cannot find such a path `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` in my system of El-Capitan.

Comment: @Masi I gave up and started using Canopy under an academic license.  Hope you solved your problem.

Comment: @user2738815 Please, post your proposal as an answer or wiki answer here. - - I solved my case with OS shift to Debian Linux where I have not had any such problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use conda to create separate python enviornments, each with a different $PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213476/how-to-use-conda-to-create-separate-python-enviornments-each-with-a-different)