# How to let Anaconda Python and node-gyp co-exist?

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, anaconda, node-modules, node-gyp

I am primarily a node.js developer and many npm modules use `node-gyp` which requires `python 2.7` and `python 3.x.x` is not [recommended](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation).

The other day I was trying my hand at learning Python and was recommended to install Anaconda while following the tutorial. This defaulted the python version to version `3.x`.

The next time i tried a `npm install` I started seeing errors with `npm ERR! iltorb@1.0.13 install: node-gyp rebuild`.

This led me to muck around a bit and finally removing Anaconda returned the python version to the system default of `2.7` and everything was back to normal in node.js land.

So my question now is, if I want to let Anaconda co-exist on my system with with my node.js based development, how do I do it ?

Comment: You can download the `python-2.7` variant of anaconda at https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use conda to create separate python enviornments, each with a different $PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213476/how-to-use-conda-to-create-separate-python-enviornments-each-with-a-different)